# How to power a DC brushless motor without a speed controller

Tags: power-supply, motor

I have a brushless motor but It doesn't power directly with a 9 volt battery, but I don't have a speed controller what else can I use to power it.

Comment: Step 1: check that you haven't destroyed it yet.

Comment: Can I use a switch or speed controller from a fan, I tested it long ago and it controls the speed of a brushed DC but I don't have it now. Can I use this to power it?

Comment: No, not at all. Magnetic fields as they are used in motors have to be changing. Brushed DC motors do this by putting current through different coils as the motor spins. The spinning itself changes the coil that is getting the current (or the direction the current travels through a single coil). In a brushless motor, there is no mechanical mechanism to change the magnetic fields. It still uses different coils to change magnetic fields, but it requires this brushless motor controller to decide when to change the current to alternating coils.

Comment: But can I use the motor to generate electricity without using any sort of controller, By spinning the rotor manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brushless motors do not have commutators so they cannot be powered directly from DC sources such as batteries.  You'll have to procure a brushless motor driver from somewhere in order to use the motor.